# Dynamic selects in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have class PersonSummary, which combines properties (columns) from 2 database tables Person and Address (with a foreign key of Person), so a PersonSummary has a First Name, State and Zip.

The creation of PersonSummary could be in a select clause with 
(person, address => new PersonSummary {person, address} )

My data access layer has no knowledge of PersonSummary, so I'd like to add the select clause at a higher level, and only construct the from, where, etc. at a lower level, to select rows from Person and Address based on different criteria, for e.g. have methods like GetFemales() or GetPeopleInAState().

Any recommendations on how to do this? Should my data-access functions return Expressions and the higher level method just tacks on a Select clause to it?

Signatures/Return types most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using the underlying extension methods LINQ uses, you can pretty much do anything you want.

So als long as your data layer returns IQueryable information, you could say

```
var withSummary = db.GetFemales()
                    .Select( p => new PersonSummary(p, p.Address) );
```

If you're using LINQ to SQL or EF, all data is retrieved with a single query. If, however, your LINQ provider is less advanced, you could try

```
var withSummary = db.GetFemales().AsEnumerable()
                    .Select( p => new PersonSummary(p, p.Address) );
```

But that does require you to somehow preload (or lazy load) the address.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add extensions to IQueryable:

```
public static IQueryable<Person> Famales(IQueryable<Person> this entry)
{
    return entry.Where(p => p.Gender == Gender.Female);
}

public static IQueryable<Person> LivingInState(IQueryable<Person> this entry, State state)
{
    return entry.Where(p => p.State == state);
}

public static IQueryable<Person> PeopleWithAddress(IQueryable<Person> this entry)
{
    return entry.Where(p => p.Address != null);
}

// Use like this
var marriedFemales = GetPersonsQuery().Females().Where(f => f.IsMarried)
var femaleVictorians = GetPersonsQuery().Females().LivingInState(State.Victoria)
var femaleVictorians = GetPersonsQuery().PeopleWithAddress()
    .Females().Where(x => x.IsMarried)
    .Select( x => new { x.LastName, x.Address} )
```

Comment: thanks, that is a great start.

Now can I further split the GetPersonQuery() so I can have the from and joins in the data layer and the select/projection in the business layer?
One way is to define a PersonAddress entity in the data layer that will have the Person and Address, but I'd like to avoid that.

So, for e.g. Write a PeopleWithAddresses() method (I don't know what return type it would be), and have

var marriedFemales = PeopleWithAddresses().Females().Where( f => f.IsMarried).Select new {Person.LastName, Address.State) }
or just .Select Person.Age

Comment: You can easily do it. I'll updated the answer with another sample.